# Why does data.table lose class definition in .SD after group by?

Tags: r, class, data.table

I've tried to attach my own class to a `numeric`, to alter the output `format`.  This works fine, but after I do a group `by` the class reverts back to numeric.

Example:
Define a new format function for my class:

```
format.myclass <- function(x, ...){
  paste("!!", x, "!!", sep = "")
}
```

Then make a small `data.table` and change one of the columns to myclass:

```
> DT <- data.table(L = rep(letters[1:3],3), N = 1:9)
> setattr(DT$N, "class", "myclass")
> DT
   L     N
1: a !!1!!
2: b !!2!!
3: c !!3!!
4: a !!4!!
5: b !!5!!
6: c !!6!!
7: a !!7!!
8: b !!8!!
9: c !!9!!
```

Now perform a group by and the N column reverts to integer:

```
> DT[, .SD, by = L]
   L N
1: a 1
2: a 4
3: a 7
4: b 2
5: b 5
6: b 8
7: c 3
8: c 6
9: c 9

> DT[, sapply(.SD, class), by = L]
   L      V1
1: a integer
2: b integer
3: c integer
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because whenever R subsets a vector it just throws away the class. Why? Well, because its an aRse, that's why. You need to write a "["-subset method.

```
> DT[,N]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
attr(,"class")
[1] "myclass"
> DT[1:2,N]
[1] 1 2
```

see how subsetting the vector has removed the class? That's the problem. data.table is doing this at some point to your vector. Write a "[" method (just copy the one that Date uses):

```
"[.myclass"= function (x, ..., drop = TRUE){
    cl <- oldClass(x)
    class(x) <- NULL
    val <- NextMethod("[")
    class(val) <- cl
    val
}

> DT[1:2,N]
[1] 1 2
attr(,"class")
[1] "myclass"
```

and now it has some class. This also fixes your last line with the sapply:

```
> DT[, sapply(.SD, class), by = L]
   L      V1
1: a myclass
2: b myclass
```

Comment: +1 too. I would have sworn `.SD` retained column attributes but clearly not. Will fix that, unless there would be any downside? (I know there won't be any performance downside, so I mean otherwise).

Comment: I really don't know why this isn't the default behaviour. Or how many copies of "[.Date" are sitting around on CRAN under different aliases. The real solution would be to subclass from "Date" and get that subset function for free :) j/k

Answer (score 3):

**This is now fixed in [v1.8.11, commit 1005+](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=240). From [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable&pathrev=1005):**

> o  That `.SD` doesn't retain column's class is now fixed. Thanks to Corone for reporting here on SO:
>        [Why does data.table lose class definition in .SD after group by?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753411/why-does-data-table-lose-class-definition-in-sd-after-group-by)